# How do I achieve new lines in output from template nodes using Mustache?

Tags: mustache, node-red

Normal line breaks in template nodes seems to be converted to whitespaces.

Example:

```
Foo: foo
Bar: bar
```

prints as `Foo: foo Bar: bar` by the debugger node.

I thought the problem described [here](https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer/issues/61) was the same but using `</br>` - as suggested - only results in `"</br>"` being added to the output.

Also tried `\n` and some other variants

Comment: Hi, the Debug node doesn't render HTML, or line breaks. The template node itself will be outputting a payload with the line breaks in as you would expect. If you configure the Debug node to output to "debug tab and console" you'll see the raw output on the console is properly formatted.

Comment: Ah I see, it is indeed formatted correctly in the console. Is there any work around to print line breaks in the debug window?

Comment: No there isn't. We plan to make the debug tab more functional in the future to make it easier to display and explore the messages sent to it, but that isn't there today.